# echoing selected data using php

Tags: php, sql

I am currently trying to echo data which I have selected from a database using the following code:

```
(DB Connection line) 

 $sqlQ = 'SELECT w_Continent.ID, w_Continent.NAME as continent_name, w_Country.Name, w_Country.Continent FROM w_Continent JOIN w_Country ON w_Continent.ID = w_Country.Continent';
        //Execute SQL Query
        $stmtRow = $db->query($sqlQ);


<?php foreach($stmtRow->fetchAll() as $cont):;?>
        <?php echo $cont['continent_name']; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, when checking the browser, this does not have the continents listed.

Comment: Can you show us a small example how your tables involved looks like? Seems to be something related to your query most likely. I ran the code using my own database and it displayed fine.

Comment: After the $stmtRow = $db->query($sqlQ); add a print_r($stmtRow->fetchAll()); Does it show the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data listed you have to add this line to your code, after echoing "continent_name".

```
<?php echo "<br/>"; ?>
```

Or you can add "\n" and view listed text in "View Source" page of your browser.

```
<?php echo "\n"; ?>
```

Comment: Data should display fine without adding a new line. OP was asking why no data was being shown at all.

Comment: This problem has been solved, however I am now posed with the following issue: